# Calculate time between records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of events with datestamps, and I'd like to display the time interval between events.  For example, if I had

```
event  |  datestamp
-------------------
  a    |   05:00
  b    |   07:00
  c    |   08:00
  d    |   12:00
 ...
```

I'd like to write a simple query that gives me

```
event  |  datestamp  |  last | since_last
-----------------------------------------
  a    |   05:00     |  NULL |  NULL
  b    |   07:00     |   a   |  2 hours
  c    |   08:00     |   b   |  1 hour
  d    |   12:00     |   c   |  4 hours
```

The format of the last column is unimportant -- it can be milliseconds, seconds, something human readable, whatever's easy.  Also note that the actual data has proper datetimes, I'm just too lazy to type the date out.

The important part is that there is nothing in the record for "b" that points to "a" as the immediately-previous event, so a solution like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712494/how-to-calculate-time-between-records-in-sql-server-2008) doesn't work -- I need some syntax to select all records JOINed to the most recent older record.

What I've tried looks like

```
SELECT new.event, new.datestamp, old.event AS last,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MAX(old.datestamp), new.datestamp) AS since_last
FROM events AS new, events AS old
WHERE new.datestamp > old.datestamp
LIMIT 10;
```

but it just appears to hang -- I let it run for over a minute.  Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678447/store-time-between-records), I tried

```
SELECT event, datestamp,
  (SELECT MAX(old.datestamp)
   FROM events old
   WHERE new.datestamp > old.datestamp
  ) last_ds
FROM events new
LIMIT 10;
```

This actually works but takes over 14 seconds on my table with a million events, even though I'm only selecting 10 records, so something must be wrong.

Comment: You're selecting 10 records but the inner query has to do the calculation for your million+ records.

Comment: if you want your last 10 records is it not possible to limit your inner query to the last 10 records by timestamp?

Comment: Hrm.  Given a single record, I know how to write a query for "select the record with the highest datestamp that's less than `myrecord.datestamp`", and that query returns instantaneously.  I guess I need to "nest" that somehow instead?

Comment: In the real implementation, events have a "type" and I wanted to calculate the time between events of a given type.  I can use the answers below to write a stored procedure that filters the table on one type, but ideally I'd like to be able to write a view that shows all events of all types, and the time since the last same-typed event.  I may ask a separate question for that case.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "date arithmetic".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
select event,datestamp,
       @PrevEvent as last,  
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @PrevDate, datestamp) AS since_last,
       @PrevDate:=datestamp,
       @PrevEvent:=event
from events, (select @PrevDate:=null,@PrevEvent:=null) t
order by datestamp
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fc3c/3)

To select last 10 events just use a subquery with LIMIT instead of just `events` table.

```
select event,datestamp,
       @PrevEvent as last,  
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @PrevDate, datestamp) AS since_last,
       @PrevDate:=datestamp,
       @PrevEvent:=event
from ( select *
       from events
       order by datestamp DESC
       LIMIT 10
     ) t1, (select @PrevDate:=null,@PrevEvent:=null) t
order by datestamp
```

**UPD:**

To get right first row (not NULL since_last field) in 10 recent you should first LIMIT 11 (10+1) in the inner subquery and then in the outer query `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1`.

```
select event,datestamp,last,since_last
FROM
(
select event,datestamp,
       @PrevEvent as last,  
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @PrevDate, datestamp) AS since_last,
       @PrevDate:=datestamp,
       @PrevEvent:=event
from ( select *
       from events
       order by datestamp DESC
       LIMIT 11
     ) t1, (select @PrevDate:=null,@PrevEvent:=null) t
order by datestamp
) t3 
LIMIT 10 offset 1
```

Comment: The first 2 columns are a bit redundant, but otherwise it should work.

Comment: This solution is fast and effective, but I'm not sure how I'd change it to see the most recent events instead of the oldest ones.  Note that I have a million+ events, and I mostly care about recent ones.

Comment: @Coderer I've added a query to select most recent records.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select event,datestamp,last,since_last FROM
(select event,datestamp,
       @PrevEvent as last,  
       concat((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @PrevDate, datestamp))/3600,
              ' Hours') AS since_last,
       @PrevDate:=datestamp,
       @PrevEvent:=event
from events, (select @PrevDate:=null,@PrevEvent:=null) t
order by datestamp) abc
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fc3c/7)**

Comment: Clever use of the nested select to hide the superfluous values that come from variable assignment.  You could also remove `event` and `datestamp` from the select and replace `@PrevDate:=datestamp` with `(@PrevDate:=datestamp) AS datestamp`, etc.  The columns are in the "wrong" order but that doesn't really matter.